# Can't pass $post-ID into fpdb function wordpress admin screen

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, pdf

I'm wondering if anyone can help me. I'm trying to generate a PDF based on a SQL query from the wordpress database. The query needs to be dynamic and only show the results based from the $post->ID of the current page in the Wordpress admin screen.

I'm using the FPDB PDF library and have created a function output_pdf in which I'm trying to pass the $post->ID as an argument.

However, when I try running this I keep getting an undefined object error. It's frustrating because when I manually add the ID as an argument it works like so

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'my_function_with_wc_functions' );
  function my_function_with_wc_functions() {
  if( isset($_POST['generate_posts_pdf'])) {
    output_pdf(72);
  }
}
```

When I print the `$post->ID` within the `my_function_with_wc_functions()` I can see the ID being outputted so I'm unsure to why this isn't being passed into the `output_pdf` function.

Can anyone help please?

```
$pdf = new PDF_HTML();


add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'my_function_with_wc_functions' );
  function my_function_with_wc_functions() {
  global $post;
  $post = $post ? $post : get_post($_GET['post']);
  if( isset($_POST['generate_posts_pdf'])) {
    output_pdf($post->ID);
  }
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'as_fpdf_add_custom_box');
function as_fpdf_add_custom_box()
{
    $screens = ['product'];
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
            'as_fpdf_box_id',           // Unique ID
            'Entry List',  // Box title
            'as_fpdf_create_admin_page',  // Content callback, must be of type callable
            $screen,                   // Post type
            'normal'                  // Priority
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'as_fpdf_create_admin_menu' );
function as_fpdf_create_admin_menu() {
    $hook = add_submenu_page(
        'tools.php',
        'Atomic Smash PDF Generator',
        'Atomic Smash PDF Generator',
        'manage_options',
        'as-fdpf-tutorial',
        'as_fpdf_create_admin_page'
    );
}

function output_pdf($id) {
    global $wpdb;

      if ( $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT lottery_id FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'wc_lottery_log WHERE lottery_id= %d', $id ) ) ) {

      $log = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'wc_lottery_log WHERE lottery_id=%d', $id ) );

      global $pdf;
      $title_line_height = 10;
      $content_line_height = 8;

      $pdf->AddPage();
      $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 42 );
      $pdf->Write(20, 'Atomic Smash FPDF Tutorial');

      foreach( $log as $row ) {
          $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 22 );
          $pdf->Write($title_line_height, 'Test');
          // Add a line break
          $pdf->Ln(15);
          // Post Content
          $pdf->Ln(10);
          $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 12 );
          $pdf->WriteHTML($row->ticketid);
        }
    }
    $pdf->Output('D','atomic_smash_fpdf_tutorial.pdf');
    exit;
}

function as_fpdf_create_admin_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Generate Entry List</h1>
    <p>Click below to generate a pdf all all lottery entries. </p>
      <form method="post" id="as-fdpf-form">
        <button class="button button-primary" type="submit" name="generate_posts_pdf" value="generate">Generate PDF from Competiion Entries</button>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
}
```

EDIT

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'my_function_with_wc_functions' );
  function my_function_with_wc_functions() {

  global $post;
  $post = $post ? $post : get_post($_GET['post']);
  $id = $post->ID;
  print_r($post);

  if( isset($_POST['generate_posts_pdf'])) {
    output_pdf($id);
  }
}
```

returns

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 72
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2019-01-09 13:36:07
    [post_date_gmt] => 2019-01-09 13:36:07
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => Test5
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => open
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => test5-2
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2019-01-10 13:46:08
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-01-10 13:46:08
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => /?post_type=product&#038;p=72
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => product
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)
```

Error being printed out when running the output_pdf()

```
Notice: Undefined index: post in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial.php on line 23

Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined variable: pdf in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial.php on line 85

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function Output() on null in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial.php:85
Stack trace:
#0 /app/public/wp-content/plugins/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial.php(28): output_pdf(NULL)
#1 /app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): my_function_with_wc_functions('')
#2 /app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#3 /app/public/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /app/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-woocommerce.php(503): do_action('woocommerce_ini...')
#5 /app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): WooCommerce->init('')
#6 /app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#7 /app/public/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#8 /app/public/wp-settings.php(467): do_action('init')
#9 /app/public/wp-config.php(76): require_once('/app/public/wp-...')
#10 /app/public/wp-load.php(37): require_o in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial/atomicsmash-pdf-tutorial.php on line 85
```

Comment: Have you print the $post data, what you are getting in it?

Comment: Hi, when i print_r($post) i get the post object

Comment: Just can't seem to pass the $post->ID into the output_pdf

Comment: share your printed output

Comment: I've updated the question with the output

Comment: I've added the error message i'm getting too incase that helps

Comment: @dipmala Can you see what the problem might be?

Comment: The first error message is telling you that, apparently, `$_GET['post']` is null (there's no `post` variable in `$_GET`). Seeing that a few lines below you're using `$_POST` instead, shouldn't `$_GET['post']` be `$_POST['post']`? Maybe that's part of the problem.

Comment: Actually, yes, it should be `$_POST['post']` instead of `$_GET['post']`. However, your form doesn't contain any `post` field either so `$_POST['post']` will too result in `Notice: Undefined index: post in (...)`. You really should fix your code.

Comment: Hi @cabrerahector the $_POST is only being used for $_POST['generate_posts_pdf'] to check that the button has been clicked? I'm using $_GET['post'] to get the post parameter in the url so I can pass this onto the output_pdf() function.

Comment: As you can tell, however, that's not working. Include the post ID with your form (eg. hidden field), follow my suggestion from above and you should be able to get some progress.

Comment: Ok thanks @cabrerahector. I'll try what you've suggested and let you know how i get on

Comment: @cabrerahector Storing the post id in the form and using $_POST works

Comment: If you provide an answer, i'm more than happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the PHP notice says, `$_GET['post']` is indeed not set. Your form sends data via `$_POST`, so in order for your script to work you need to:

1. Change `$_GET['post']` to `$_POST['post']`.
2. Include the post ID with your form. Currently, the only data it sends is the name of your submit button. Include the ID of the current post via a hidden field named `post`, then your script will work.